# can't order alphabetically ASC does not distinguish uppercase

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by, android-sqlite

everyone! I have a question, im making a project in Android Studio so im working with database (all is well until here) but when try make a list of my registers ordening alphabetically does not distinguish uppercase :( for example when i make the consulte my resulst is this:

- Ana
- Bety
- Carlos
- Gonzales
- Zod
- armando
- beto
- carolinna
- francisco
- zoe

This is my result, but i want this result:

- armando
- Ana
- beto
- Bety
- Carlos
- carolinna
- francisco
- Zod
- zoe

I use this code:

```
public Cursor queryallclientes(){
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"id","name"};
        return db.query"tablename",columnas,null,null,null,null,"name"+ asc,null);
    }
```

**thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

> COLLATE

Like this,

```
public Cursor queryallclientes(){
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"id","name"};
        return db.query"tablename",columnas,null,null,null,null,"name+" COLLATE NOCASE ASC;",null);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, i edited my code (cause had a sintaxis error) and i posted the answer, i use the COLLATE NOCASE ASC

Comment: Sure.. You can mark the answer if it had helped!! :)